# How to change the backgroundand text color of the navbar on scroll in react.js?

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs

I am trying to add a transparent navbar in react.js now i want to change the background and text color of the navbar on scroll .

```
    <div className="logo">
      <a href='/'>
      <img alt='logo' src={require('./images/local/Wings-Logo-512.png')}/>
      </a>
    </div>
```

The background color should change on scoll.[image: corrently it looks like this.]

Answer (score 2):

Should be fixed by using window.scrollY

```
const [navBackground, setNavBackground] = useState(false)
  const navRef = useRef()
  navRef.current = navBackground
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const show = window.scrollY > 670
      if (navRef.current !== show) {
        setNavBackground(show)
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    }
  }, [])

//then
<Navbar
    backgroundColor={navBackground ? 'white' : 'transparent'}
    style={{ transition: '1s ease' }}
  />
```